# What is the difference in publishing dotnet apps for ubuntu using specific ubuntu RIDs instead of non-distribution specific linux-x64?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-sdk, dotnet-publish, dotnetcorecli, runtime-identifier

What difference does it make, if any, publishing a dotnet application for ubuntu using, say,
`dotnet publish [...] -r ubuntu.20.04`
instead of
`dotnet publish [...] -r linux-x64`

Performance tweaks, better support... ?! can't answer that from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

I have an azure pipeline that releases the app to several different platforms, I would surely prefer using the more general linux-x64 for debian based distributions, instead of having to deal with their specific RIDs.

I wonder, though, if with that benefit I am giving up other non-neglectable ones.